# Count post with specific categories and tags laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have 3 model `Post, Tag and Category`. `Post model` and `Tag model` are in many to many relationship with pivot table and `Post model` and `Category model` are in one to many relation.

For example let's  assume I have following tags and categories:

`tag name = php,`

`category name = tutorial, project, testing`

`no. of post having above attribute = 3 [ all post have different category, same tag]`

I'm trying to count posts and show category name having above category and tag `php` in view  named `archive-php`.

This is what i have done so far:

My method in controller

```
 public function countTag()
{
    $posts = Post::whereHas('tag', function($r) {
            $r->where('name','=', "php");
        })->get();
    return view('archive-php')
           ->withPosts($posts)
}
```

My code in view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <li><a href="#">{{ucfirst($post->category->name)}}</a>
         {{$post->count()}}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

The above code sucessfully shows the related category name (3 category name) `dd($posts);` dumps 3 array but counts all post in the db. What piece of puzzle i'm missing here or it is impossible  ?

Comment: You want to count the number of [posts] of type [category] having tag [php]?

Comment: Yes , that is what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you should get all categories. And then get/count posts that have `php` tag

1 - method

```
$categories = Category::all();

foreach($categories as $category) {
  $category->phpPosts = Post::where('category_id', '=', $category->id)->whereHas('tag', function($r) {
            $r->where('name','=', "php");
        })->get();
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <li><a href="#">{{ucfirst($category->name)}}</a>
         {{ $category->phpPosts->count() }}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

It can be done by easy way something like:

2 - method

```
$categories = App\Category::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('tag', function($r) {
            $r->where('name','=', "php");
        });
}])->get();
```

But I'm not sure whether it is correct. Try the method 1. If I got you correctly.